# TypeError: 'function' object is not subscriptable error on dataframe and barplot

Tags: python

```
Df = pd.DataFrame({
    'Day of the week' : ['Mon','Tue','Wed','Thu','Fri','Sat','Sun'],
    'Hours' : [2,2.9,3.1,3.6,2.1,3.9,3.3]})
sns.boxplot(x ='Day of the week', y ='Hours', data = df, color = 'gray')
```

I'm trying to make a bar plot for daily hours of using YouTube.

But I have troulbe with both lines. They both show error says  **TypeError: 'function' object is not subscriptable
**
How can I fix this?

Barplot that y axix is hour and x axis is day of week.

Comment: This code does not have any problems (besides `Df` vs `df` naming). Examine your full error trace to see where the error occurs. Include the full error message in your post.

Answer (score 0):

There is no problem in your code and your code looks like this for your data plot:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'Day of the week' : ['Mon','Tue','Wed','Thu','Fri','Sat','Sun'],
    'Hours' : [2,2.9,3.1,3.6,2.1,3.9,3.3]})
sns.barplot(x ='Day of the week', y ='Hours', data = df, palette = 'gray')
```

**Result will be:**

[image]